# having problem creating a loop for my jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this scripts that works. As of now it changes the image correctly for the last set, I want to put it in a loop where I have m=k, but it does not work

like

```
for (m = 0; m < k; ++m) {
    <script>
    $(function() {
         var m = 1;
         var resultb = $('[id^=input_]').filter(function () {
             return this.id.match(/input_\d+$/); //regex for the pattern "input_ followed by a number"
         }).length;
         var  k = resultb;
         m = k;

         $("#input_"+m).change(function() {
             var val = $("#input_"+m+" option:selected").text(); 
             var valval = $("#input_"+m+"option:selected").val(); 
             var n = val.indexOf('(');
             val = val.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : val.length);
             var img_option='images/sample/'+val+'.jpg';
             if ($("#input_"+m+" option:selected").val() > 0)   
                 $("a.lb:first").html( "<img src="+ img_option+">");
             $('a.lb:first img').css({'width' : '350px' });
             $('a.lb:first img').addClass( "img-fluid" );
         });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: By the look of things, your `m` is 1-based, so you want `for( m=1; m<=k; m++)`

Comment: no this has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `m` values appear to be 1-based, so your loop will want to start at `1`.

That being said, you don't need a `for` loop at all. Just select the elements you want:

```
$(function() {
   const inputs = $('[id^=input_]').filter(function () {
      return this.id.match(/input_\d+$/); //regex for the pattern "input_ followed by a number"
   });
   inputs.on('change', function() {
      // I'm assuming that `#input_X` is actually a `<select>`, not an `<input>`
      // You should probably adjust your naming convention to be less confusing
      let text = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
      let value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

      let parenthesis = text.indexOf("(");
      if( parenthesis > -1) text = text.substring(0, parenthesis);

      let source = `images/sample/${text}.jpg`;
      if( value > 0) $("a.lb:first").html(`<img src="${source}" style="width: 350px" class="img-fluid" />`);
   });
});
```

You'll notice I've given your variables more reasonable names, used `let` and `const` as somewhat more appropriate, and just generally tidied the code up to be as clean and understandable as possible.

Comment: everything works except that there is a blank space added before .jpg.  this space dose actually exist

Comment: so I changed  let parenthesis = text.indexOf("(")-1; and it works